# Transaction expired inside Phantom wallet

Tags: phantom, transaction

Has anyone experienced this "Transaction expired" issue inside Phantom and knows how to fix it?

Im trying to make a transaction in my local environment, and it used to work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I had to change the phantom wallet to use localhost.

Comment: Going forward, the Phantom should always be set to the same network as the dapp that's requesting the tx. This error shows because Phantom doesn't recognize the blockhash that's on localhost when it looks for it on mainnet. We'll improve this error message and make it easier to change to the correct network!

Comment: Hi @BrianFriel, I have definitely seen you as an author for some Solana blog! Thanks for sharing the knowledge.
It was just weird to me, since it must have been a recent update. Previously, my wallet could be connected to mainnnet and I would still be able to interact with Apps in local env.